# Jasmine spy element onload

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm creating dynamically some scripts like this:

```
  var js1 = document.createElement('script');
  js1.type = 'text/javascript';
  js1.src = '/js-1.js';
  docmuent.body.appendChild(js1);
  js1.onload = function() {
     var js2 = document.createElement('script');
     js2.type = 'text/javascript';
     js2.src = '/js-2.js';
     document.body.appendChild(js2);
  };
```

Here's my spec:

```
  it('Tests inject script', function() {
    expect($("script[src*='/js-1.js']").length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    expect($("script[src*='/js-2.js']").length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
```

The test on js-2 always fails. How can i spy js-1 onload event ?

Comment: Has the same issue with testing image.onload callback

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in your ordering. You should create the `script` tag, add it to the `body`, set the `onload`, and then set the `src`.

```
var js1 = document.createElement('script');
js1.type = 'text/javascript';
docmuent.body.appendChild(js1);
js1.onload = function() {
   var js2 = document.createElement('script');
   js2.type = 'text/javascript';
   document.body.appendChild(js2);
   js2.src = '/js-2.js';
};
js1.src = '/js-1.js';
```

Comment: i made the changes but i still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the tag creation code inside the onload event. If I'm not wrong IE will only start downloading the file as soon as the script tag is added to the DOM.

My suggestion is to move everything you have in the onload event outside and maybe have a handler function inside the onload event to know for sure when the file has finished loading.
This way your only problem will be testing the call of the function inside the onload event. You can do that by mocking document.createElement('script'); and return a fake object that you can use like "fakeObject.onload()" and spy if your inner helper function is called.